# Direction of current in Multiple Batteries

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

In multiloop circuits where we have to apply Kirchoff law, with multiple batteries, I am having a bit of difficulty figuring out what direction and from which battery would the current originate. [image]

For example take this circuit where would the current originate and why and in which direction?

Comment: I think it depends upon the emf of these sources. You may originate the current from any direction and the answers which you will get would be according to $+$ and $-$ signs

Comment: A hint: for specified emf's, set up the Kirchhoff loop equations, and assume a direction for all loop currents.  When you solve the system of equations, any loop current that is negative indicates that the current actually flows in the opposite direction from the assumed directionl

Comment: Don't think of those battery symbols as representing real batteries. Think of them as _[ideal voltage sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_source)_. An ideal voltage source can't really exist, but if it did, it would maintain a constant voltage difference between it's two terminals with no dependence on either the magnitude or the direction of the current flowing through it.

Comment: P.S., A real battery, when operated within certain limits, acts almost like an ideal voltage source in series with a low-value resistor, and when the circuit forces current to flow the "wrong way" through the battery, that will _charge_ the battery. (But note! some batteries are not designed to survive re-charging, and the chemical processes that cause or are caused by the current flow damage the battery's physical structure.)

Comment: Thanks a lot people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> take this circuit where would the current originate

Current must flow in complete loops. Or put another way, charge is a conserved quantity. So current doesn't have an origin the way, for example, electric field does.

> and why and in which direction?

Since R1 has a voltage source directly across it, you should be able to find the direction of current through that resistor immediately. But consider what might happen if $\varepsilon_2$ has a negative value.

For R2, you can write a KVL equation for the upper loop and also get its current very quickly. But the actual direction will depend on the values of $\varepsilon_1$, $\varepsilon_2$, and $\varepsilon_3$.

Answer (score 2):

> For example take this circuit where would the current originate and why and in which direction?

One of the great things about circuit theory is that it doesn’t matter. Just guess. If you guess right the number will be positive and if you guess wrong then the number will be negative. But negative numbers are perfectly valid so it doesn’t matter!

When I do mesh current analysis I always just assume every mesh current goes clockwise.

Comment: Thanks a ton Dale

Comment: A well accepted answer with a green tick cannot have zero score.